# Amazon OpenSearch: how many searches per index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have a cluster containing two indexes, and I'd like to see how many searches are going to each index. In the Amazon OpenSearch UI, and in Cloudwatch, I can see that the search rate is being tracked, but only at the cluster level, not at the index level. Is there any way to get this information?

Background: one of the indexes is being retired, and I want to make sure that there isn't any code out there still using it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have FGAC enabled you can enable audit logs and check in cloudwatch insights where the index is accessed and by who.